# Change the title of message box in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I am displaying a message box using this code

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "successfull", "alert('Your email has been sent successfully!'); window.location = 'www.mypage.com/Default.aspx';", true)
```

it's working properly now i want to change the title of this message box then how can i do this

title is - the page //localhost says 
but i want the title - Record Information

Answer (score 2):

you can't change title of standard Alert window. the only way is to create pseudo-modal window on javascript, html and css.

here are some examples on jquery:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
- http://fancybox.net/
- http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html
- http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

.. or some asp.net controls:

- http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/PopupControl/ModalWindow.aspx
- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/windowmanager/defaultcs.aspx